# Is it possible to connect to server management studio database from joomla?

Tags: php, sql-server, joomla

I am trying a simple datababase connection from a joomla website, to a server management studio database.I have tried serveral different ways, srv, dbo etc.
 It still displays errors in its simplest form.
Is it possible to establish such a connection?

Error messages:

```
Unable to load Database Driver: mssql
 Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() 

 Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()
```

simplest:

```
<?php
// Create a link to MSSQL
$con = mssql_connect('server1', 'name', 'pass');

// Select the database 'php'
mssql_select_db('database1', $con);
?>
```

way2:

```
<?php
$servername = "s1";
$username = "u1";
$password = "p1";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$servername;Database=db1", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $setAttribute = $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Comment: What does your error say?

Comment: Updated the question. Errors say that the driver is not recognized, and functions not recognized.

Comment: Do you have PDO_SQLSRV installed/loaded in your server? if not, please visit http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php

Comment: @AMINCHAR Downloaded exe and zip files and uploaded them to server. It's not working.  Unable to load Database Driver: mssql.
Any more specific instructions please?

Comment: You need to activate the extension in your PHP.ini file, did you already make this? If yes, then please check in your server logs to see if there is any error when your server tries to load the extention